# SELECT grouping by value in field

Tags: mysql, sql

Given the following (greatly simplified) example table:

```
CREATE TABLE `permissions` (
    `name` varchar(64) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    `access` enum('read_only','read_write') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'read_only'
);
```

And the following example contents:

```
| name | access     |
=====================
| foo  | read_only  |
| foo  | read_write |
| bar  | read_only  |
```

What I want to do is run a `SELECT` query that fetches one row for each unique value in `name`, favouring those with an `access` value of `read_write`, is there a way that this can be done? i.e- such that the results I would get are:

```
foo | read_write |
bar | read_only  |
```

I may need to add new options to the `access` column in future, but they will always be in order of importance (lowest to highest) so, if possible, a solution that can cope with this would be especially useful.

Also, to clarify, my actual table includes other fields than these, which is why I'm not using a unique key on the `name` column; there will be multiple rows by name by design to suit various criteria.

Comment: The best way to do this really depends on what the "future" data might look like in access and what you would want returned. For example, would you like access sorted in alphabetical order unless there is a "read_write" entry?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following will work on your data:

```
select name, max(access)
from permissions
group by name;
```

However, this orders by the string values, not the indexes.  Here is another method:

```
select name,
       substring_index(group_concat(access order by access desc), ',') as access
from permissions
group by name;
```

It is rather funky that `order by` goes by the index but `min()` and `max()` use the character value.  Some might even call that a bug.

Answer (score 2):

You can create another table with the priority of the `access` (so you can add new options), and then group by and find the `MIN()` value of the priority table:

E.g. create a table called `Priority` with the values

```
| PriorityID| access     |
========================
| 1         | read_write |
| 2         | read_only  |
```

And then,

```
SELECT A.Name, B.Access
FROM (
    SELECT A.name, MIN(B.PriorityID) AS Most_Valued_Option  -- This will be 1 if there is a read_write for that name
    FROM permissions A
    INNER JOIN Priority B
    ON A.Access = B.Access
    GROUP BY A.Name ) A
INNER JOIN Priority B
ON A.Most_Valued_Option = B.PriorityID   
   -- Join that ID with the actual access 
   -- (and we will select the value of the access in the select statement)
```

Comment: I don't see any need to manufacture a tornado just to blow out a match.

Comment: How would you solve the need to 'add new options to the `access` column in future'? (I'm concerned that the new options won't be ordered by importance that matches the alphabetical ordering)

Comment: How would you solve the need for a different priority order for a different query? I'm concerned that this "priority" for access is related more to the *query* than it is to the permission.

Comment: If you have a different priority order, you would change the order based on the PriorityID.

Comment: If query ***one*** needs a particular order of preference/priority for `access`, and query ***two*** needs a *different* order for preferenc/priority... how would this proposed solution address that? To the question about addressing possible future requirements for specifying an order that is not alphabetical, *and* for returning not just the preferred/priority `access` but other columns on that same row, I've posted an answer that uses the `FIELD` and `ELT` functions. The query in my answer is overkill for current requirements; the solution from Gordon is sufficient No extra table required..

Answer (score 1):

The solution proposed by Gordon is sufficient for the current requirements.

If we anticipate a future requirement for a priority order to be other than alphabetical string order (or by enum index value)...

As a modified version of Gordon's answer, I would be tempted to use the MySQL `FIELD` function and (its converse) `ELT` function, something like this:

```
SELECT p.name
     , ELT(
         MIN(
           FIELD(p.access
             ,'read_only','read_write','read_some'
           )
         )
       ,'read_only','read_write','read_some'
     ) AS access 
 FROM `permissions` p
GROUP BY p.name
```

If the specification is to pull the entire row, and not just the value of the `access` column, we could use an inline view query to find the preferred `access`, and a join back to the `preferences` table to pull the whole row...

```
SELECT p.*
  FROM ( -- inline view, to get the highest priority value of access
         SELECT r.name
              , MIN(FIELD(r.access,'read_only','read_write','read_some')) AS ax
           FROM `permissions` r
          GROUP BY r.name
       ) q
  JOIN `permissions` p
    ON p.name   = q.name
   AND p.access = ELT(q.ax,'read_only','read_write','read_some')
```

Note that this query returns not just the `access` with the highest priority, but can also return *any* columns from that row.

With the `FIELD` and `ELT` functions, we can implement any ad-hoc ordering of a list of specific, known values. Not just alphabetic ordering, or ordering by the enum index value.

That logic for "priority" can be contained within the query, and won't rely on an extra column(s) in the `permissions` table, or the contents of any other table(s).

To get the behavior we are looking for, just specifying a priority for `access`,  the "list of the values" used in the `FIELD` function will need to match the "list of values" in the `ELT` function, in the same order, and the lists should include all possible values of `access`.

---

Reference:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_elt

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_field

---

**ADVANCED USAGE**

Not that you have a requirement to do this, but considering possible future requirements... we note that...

A *different* order of the "list of values" will result in a different ordering of priority of `access`. So a variety of queries could each implement their own different rules for the "priority". Which `access` value to look for first, second and so on, by reordering the complete "list of values".

Beyond just reordering, it is also possible to *omit* a possible value from the "list of values" in the `FIELD` and `ELT` functions. Consider for example, omitting the `'read_only'` value from the list on this line:

```
              , MIN(FIELD(r.access,'read_write','read_some')) AS ax
```

and from this line:

```
  AND p.access = ELT(q.ax,'read_write','read_some')
```

That will effectively limit the `name` rows returned. Only `name` that have an `access` value of `'read_write'` or `'read_some'`. Another way to look at that, a `name` that has *only* a `'read_only'` for `access` will *not* be returned by the query.

Other modifications to the "list of values", where the lists don't "match" are also possible, to implement even more powerful rules. For example, we could exclude a `name` that has a row with `'read_only'`.

For example, in the `ELT` function, in place of the `'read_only'` value, we use a value that we know does not (and cannot) exist on any rows. To illustrate,

we can include `'read_only'` as the "highest priority" on this line...

```
              , MIN(FIELD(r.access,'read_only','read_write','read_some')) AS ax 
                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

so if a row with `'read_only'` is found, that will take priority. But in the `ELT` function in the outer query, we can translate that back to a *different* value...

```
  AND p.access = ELT(q.ax,'eXcluDe','read_write','read_some')
                          ^^^^^^^^^
```

If we know that `'eXcluDe'` doesn't exist in the `access` column, we have effectively excluded any `name` which has a `'read_only'` row, even if there is a `'read_write'` row.

Not that you have a specification or current requirement to do any of that. Something to keep in mind for future queries that do have these kinds of requirements.

Comment: I've marked Gordon's answer as correct as it's the simplest answer that solves the problem as stated. However I wanted to thank you for the detail of your answer, as I've actually found the inline view based example is the best fit for the real problem I want to solve (I think I simplified the question too much).

Comment: @Haravikk: I agree that Gordon'

Answer (score 0):

You can use distinct statement (or Group by)
SELECT distinct name, access
FROM tab;

Comment: OP could do that, but `SELECT DISTINCT name, access FROM ...` would return *both* of the rows for `name='foo'`. It would return both `read_only` and `read_write`. (The `DISTINCT` keyword applies to *all* expressions in the SELECT list.)

Answer (score 0):

This works too:

```
SELECT name, MAX(access)
  FROM permissions
GROUP BY name ORDER BY MAX(access) desc
```